# Extracting data from nested json arrays in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am having trouble extracting data from nested json in python. I want to create a one column pandas dataframe of all the values of "bill", e.g.

```
bill
----
a1
a2
a3
```

Using the output from an API formatted like this:

```
{
  "status": "succeeded",
  "travels": [
    {
      "jobs": [
        {
          "bill": "a1"
        },
        {
          "bill": "a2"
        },
        {
          "bill": "a3"
        }
      ],
      "vehicle": {
        "plate": "xyz123"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Loading the json directly into pandas gives me only the first instance of 'bill'. I have tried json_normalize() on 'jobs', but it has a key error. Can anybody help me figure out how to grab just the 'bill'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with `json_normalize`. With your input as a python dictionary `d`:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
json_normalize(d, record_path=['travels', 'jobs'])
  bill
0   a1
1   a2
2   a3
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I wasn't aware you didn't have to specify 'data' in json_normalize

Comment: Glad to help! Yeah, `json_normalize` can be finicky to get working sometimes.